# How can I disable one specific CSS file on a site, and replace it with a local version?

Tags: css, firefox, browser

I'm trying to re-skin an existing site using CSS only.  I will be taking one of their CSS files and redoing it to match a new design, without changing any HTML.  I want a good way of continually updating and then testing, but I have to do it locally because they do not have a dev environment.  The site itself is dynamic and authenticated, so I can't just download pages from the site and test the entire thing locally.  I was hoping that there is a way to tell my browser (Firefox, preferably) to disable that specific remote CSS file and replace it with a local file.

I don't want to use something like Web Develop Toolbar or Firebug because that requires me to manually make the changes each time I load a page.  I want something more seamless.

I was thinking one possibility is to load my new stylesheet in userContent.css, but I would still need a way of telling the browser not to load the original stylesheet from the server.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** I found this Mozilla bug report https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=208641 discussing the issue of being able to change userContent.css without restarting Firefox.  One of the posters (Simon Wilper) posted some files and info about adding a menu item to refresh userContent.css, but it talks about modifying browser.xul and I can't find that file on my system.  This seems like the last piece of the puzzle.

Comment: Have you tried Fiddler? http://fiddler2.com/  You can set autoresponders for specific files and point to a local file to use instead of one on the site.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AdBlock Plus to create a custom filter to block that one particular stylesheet, so it will not load when you go to the site. This rule will always be in effect, so as you refresh the page, you will not have to do anything extra.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/

As for adding your own stylesheet onto that external site, you can use Stylish, an add-on for adding your own stylesheets to particular domains. This, too, will always be present as you refresh the page.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/

The issues you will run into, I imagine, will be what to do with images you are intending on linking to in the CSS. You will have to upload them somewhere, reference them absolutely, and then once you are finished, replace the URLs with new locations on their server. Also, that editing Stylish stylesheets within their editor is pretty poor (no code colouring, no code completion.) Probably better to edit it in your editor of choice, and then paste it into the Stylish textarea. Hit save, then see your work (I believe you won't even have to refresh, but I might be wrong.)

Also, both these add-ons are available for Chrome too.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock-plus/cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for this; it does work.  You're right about the Stylish editor being annoying, though - there isn't a way to tell Stylish to use another file off my computer?

Comment: The worst thing about Stylish seems to be that it closes the file each time I save it, so I can't just leave it open to work on it.

Comment: There isn't a way to tell Stylish to use another file off your computer, **however** you could upload your `.css` file somewhere, and then within Stylish try using the `@import http://myserver.com/filename.css` rule -- check [W3C document on @import](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media0) but I'm not sure if that will work or not; just a guess. It might fail due to being a security issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why people are suggesting to install extensions for this simple task. I would suggest you to just follow these steps to disable whichever file you want from being loaded in your browser that you want. Just follow these few simple steps:

1. Hit `Ctrl + Shift + C` to open source inspection
2. Navigate to `Network` tab [image: Network Tab Opened in a browser]
3. `Right Click` on any file from the list and and click **Block request URL** [image]

Now the file won't load. Cheers!

**PS:** Steps are same for Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox browsers. Not tested on Opera and/or Safari.

Comment: this doesn't work permanently, when the page is reloaded the resource is unblocked again

Comment: For permanent settings, you need to check your browser settings if it supports it or perhaps use some extension that will block certain sort of files on the browser. For testing the web application while you constantly modify your resource files, this is a useful method to follow.

Answer (score -1):

Install web developer extension

http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/firefox/

And then it will create a menu under the Address bar, click on the css tab and then "Disable Styles" > Disable Individual Style Sheet" > then select the style sheet file you want to disable

after this, again click on the css tab and then "Add User Style Sheets" , next select your css file.